# Database Query for Oracle using two table and count function

Tags: mysql, oracle

I'm new to database systems and to this forum. I'm currently in my 2nd year undergrad program in IT and am struggling with some database queries. I have two tables that I have to query for the following information. I've copied the tables below, along with the information that I need to gather. I think I need to use a join, with a count to get the correct return, but I can't seem to get it to work.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

1. List of customer names with the number of orders that have been placed.

   ***CUSTOMER***
   **CUSTOMERID**  VARCHAR2(100 BYTE)  No      1
   **FIRSTNAME**   VARCHAR2(30 BYTE)   No      2
   **LASTNAME**    VARCHAR2(30 BYTE)   No      3
   **ADDRESS** VARCHAR2(100 BYTE)  Yes     4
   **CITY**    VARCHAR2(35 BYTE)   Yes     5
   **STATE**   VARCHAR2(25 BYTE)   Yes     6
   **COUNTRY** VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)   Yes     7
   **PHONE**   VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)   Yes     8
   **EMAIL**   VARCHAR2(35 BYTE)   No      9
   **USERNAME**    VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)   No      10
   **PASSWORD**    VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)   No      11
   **ZIP** NUMBER(9,0) Yes     12

***ORDER_TABLE***

**ORDERID** VARCHAR2(35 BYTE)   No      1
**CUSTOMERID**  VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)   No      2
**ORDERDATE**   DATE    Yes     3
**SHIPDATE**    DATE    Yes     4

Comment: Oracle DB or mysql?

Answer (score 0):

A query to do that could be:

```
select customerid, firstname, lastname, count(1)
  from customer inner join order_table using(customerid)
 group by customerid, firstname, lastname
```

You need to learn about `group by` and `aggregate function`. Since the question you have just posted is one of the first examples you will learn when studying about them.

If you don't know what a **join** is or how to use it, then you must focus on learning it. It's a fundamental concept you need to master when dealing with relational databases.